# css image with text filling 100% height

Tags: css

How to solve this one: I have a div with height 100%. In this div I want to place an image and thereunder a few lines of text (dynamic amount of text). How can I make sure the image is stretched to completely fill the space that is left from the text?

Thanks, Wienel

Comment: You should know that `100%` doesn't always mean `100%`.. it is only `100%` of the parent. If the parent is 0, then `100%` of 0 is 0... Make sure the parent is also `100%`.

Comment: Can you show what you already have in a fiddle?

Comment: Try setting the height of the image too.

Comment: But that's the problem. Because the text is of dynamic length, I don't know beforehand how large the image could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT84R/1/) what you're looking for? I used `display: table` and `display: table-row` even though this isn't really a table, but table displays are great for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, works great. Next problem is to find out how to stretch the width of the container together with the image:
http://jsfiddle.net/pv64A/

Comment: Add `#img { width: 100%; }` and `#container { width: (some amount)px; }`, as seen with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pv64A/1/).

Answer (score 0):

your parent div has 100% width which means 100% of whatever parent.  If you want your image to display to 100% of the div in question give it a class.

.imgClass {
    width: 100%
}

generally speaking you probably don't want to distort your image which is what will happen if your text is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure the image is stretched to completely fill the space that is left from the text?

You haven't shown your html structure which make it harder to answer.

But you have to create a div with an image and a paragraph. You need to set the image width to 100%

```
<div class="structure">
        <img class="imagefullsize" />
        <p class="textunderimage">Text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.imagefullsize{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.textunderimage{
    display: block;
}
```